# SQL - look for the same value in two columns

Tags: php, sql

I have this php code which returns all the rows (properties) from the database which have "London", "Paris" or "Milan" value in the column "Location".

```
$Location = 'London,Paris,Milan';
$L_clean = explode(',', $Location);

if ($Location == 'all-locations') {
}else{
    $Locations = explode(' ', $Location);
    $main["where"]["Location:IN"] = $L_clean;
}
```

The problem is that there is another column called "City" and I need to amend the code so that it would look for London, Paris and Milan matches both in "Location" and "City" columns.

I've tried to replace the string above with one of these strings but seems that it's unorrect format:

```
$main["where"]["Location OR City:IN"] = $L_clean;
$main["where"]["Location,City:IN"] = $L_clean;
```

Comment: Please explain what this has to do with SQL.  It sounds like a PHP question to me.

Comment: nobody is gonna waste time guessing is your magic DB queries work, so I suggest you see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to just use the `or` logical operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   sometable
WHERE  location IN ('London', 'Paris', 'Milan') OR
       city IN ('London', 'Paris', 'Milan')
```